# trying to link to two shared libraries that resolve the same symbol in a way that if one lib is unreachable the other is used

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking

Im writing a C application in Linux.

It uses libncurses to display data on terminal screen.

I want to use libncursesw which is the wide character supported version of ncurses. it resolves the same symbols as libncurses.

Not all linux machines have ncursesw installed. but most of them if not all of them have normal libncurses installed.

**So I want to dinamically link to libncursesw only if it is available and fallback to linking with libncurses if not.**

It seems pretty simple and general problem but I can not seem to find my answer on the web for some time now. I thoroughly read man ld and man gcc and nothing there.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to do this.

Thanks in advance :)

**I could use dlopen with RTLD_NEXT but that means strictly stating the exact shared lib ".so" file name which will probably be updated for ncurses in the future. so I need to do it with some gcc, ld, -lncurses, -lncursesw combination.**

Comment: I __strongly__ recommend against using `wchar_t` in your project, especially outside of MS Windows. On `POSIX`, `UTF-8` is used for unicode, and stuff simply works with char, without having to care about it.

Comment: **I could use dlopen with RTLD_NEXT but that means strictly stating the exact shared lib so file name which will probably be updated for ncurses in the future. so I need to do it with some gcc, ld, -lncurses, -lncursesw combination.**

Comment: thanks mic_e but how can I display russian/hebrew/arabic characters on ncurses without it?

Comment: and BTW It seems a pretty general problem concerning any dinamic lib use. Isn't it?

Comment: Edit: Sorry, it seems I was misinformed and you actually need libncursesw...